# Autocomplete Extender with WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to use Ajax Control Toolkit's Autocomplete extender with a WCF Service.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401950/is-it-possible-to-use-wcf-service-instead-of-asmx-web-service-with-ajax-control) is almost what I'm looking for, one of the answers points [to a tutorial](http://blog.magenic.com/blogs/jamesa/archive/2008/08/22/Ajax-AutoComplete-Extender-with-WCF.aspx) but I can't get it to work.

In my solution I have a web form application project and a WCF service library project.

One of the properties of the Autocomplete extender is `ServicePath` which the tutorial points to a svc file:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTextBox" Width="300" autocomplete="off" />
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender
runat="server" 
BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"
ID="autoComplete1" 
TargetControlID="myTextBox"
ServicePath="Autocomplete.svc" 
ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
MinimumPrefixLength="0" 
CompletionInterval="1000"
EnableCaching="true">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
</div>
</form>
```

Right now in `ServicePath` I'm pointing to the http address (`http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WebApp.WcfServiceLibrary/ProductService/`) that my WCF Service is running, but it just don't works.

Answer (score 1):

Is it the server or the client that isn't behaving properly?

Here are some tips on how to go about resolving your problem:

- Are you able to get the WCF service to work independently from the AJAX control? To do this, you may need to hand-craft an HTTP request to test it out.
- Are you able to get the AJAX control to create the right HTTP request? Try capturing it with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2) to see if it properly formed for what the WCF service is expecting.

Comment: I'll check that as soon as possible and post an answer or mark yours as a answer as soon as possible. Thank you very much for your time.